# Reverse geocoding using Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am using reverse geocoding in Angular app.

The needed script is added in index.html

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</scrip>
```

and the component file looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare const google: any;

export class MapComponent {

  lat;
  lng;
  address;

  constructor() {
    this.locate();
  }

  public locate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          this.lat = position.coords.latitude; // Works fine
          this.lng = position.coords.longitude;  // Works fine

          let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
          let request = {
            latLng: latlng
          };

          geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[0] != null) {
                this.address = results[0].formatted_address;  //<<<=== DOES NOT WORK, when I output this {{ address }} in the html, it's empty
                console.log(this.address);  //<<<=== BUT here it Prints the correct value to the console !!!
              } else {
                alert("No address available");
              }
            }
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Error code: " + error.code + "<br /> Error message: " + error.message);
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

and in the component html file, It's supposed to output the address

```
<div>{{ lat }}</div>        // Works fine
<div>{{ lng }}</div>        // Works fine 
<div>{{ address }}</div>    // Deosn't Work, EMPTY
```

but it's always empty,
however this line

```
console.log(this.address);
```

printed the correct value.

Comment: Thanks, your code helped me kick start my geocoder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities that I see here but cannot confirm without a reproduction, so I'll list them both.

## 1) You're not in Angular's zone

The code which changes the variable for displaying is not being executed inside Angular's zone. This tends to happen when using callbacks from third party libraries like you're doing here.

To fix, inject the `NgZone` and wrap any changes you want to see reflected in the UI with `this.ngZone.run`, like in the following snippet.

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

locate() {
  /* ... */
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.location = results[0].formatted_address
      })
  /* ... */
}
```

## 2) Wrong `this`

Somewhere along the way, you've lost the `this` which points to class instance, and you're instead writing the result into something else. You `console.log` works because that's also logging the wrong `this`, and Angular shows nothing because the *actual* property was not changed.

Comment: You saved my life :)

Comment: @M.J, for me it is showing an error as follows `ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Your component may not have been initialized when you're setting `this.location` as Angular doesn't control *when* the constructor will be called.

You should try placing `locate` call in `ngOnInit` which guarantees that your component is ready to display data bound properties:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.locate();
}
```

Comment: `You're not in Angular's zone` is correct answer here

Comment: Thank you, I tried placing the call in `ngOnInit` and it didn't work, but the `ngZone` solved the issue.